# Update translations of color attribute (label)

Tags: attributes, ce-1.9.1.0

Would anyone know how to update the translations for 'color' attribute in Magento EAV.

I need the admin value tu remain the same (after checking if it exists), then change the values of the translations for the different Storeviews.

Many thanks!

Comment: Nobody really?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goto Catalog / Attributes / Manage Attributes

Search color and edit.

Open tab Manage labels and set the labels according the right shop.

To do it programmatic you should set the option

```
$attributeId = 92; // color

/** @var $attribute \Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute */
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
$attribute->load($attributeId);

// Register attribute for the easy use of the existing block
Mage::register('entity_attribute', $attribute);

// Use options tab from edit to easy get values    
/** @var $block \Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Edit_Tab_Options */
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()
        ->getBlockSingleton('adminhtml/catalog_product_attribute_edit_tab_options');

// Get current labels, easy...
$label = $block->getLabelValues();

// Build options array
$options = array('value' => array());
foreach ($block->getOptionValues() as $optionValue) {
    $storeOption = array();
    foreach (Mage::app()->getStores(true) as $store) {
        $key = 'store' . $store->getId();
        $storeOption[$store->getId()] = $optionValue->$key;
    }
    $options['value'][$optionValue->getId()] = $storeOption;
}

// Update value #optionid for store 2
$options['value'][18][2] = 'New value';

// Show output
var_dump($label);
var_dump($options);

// Update and save data
$attribute->setFrontendLabel($label)->setOption($options)->save();
```

Comment: Sorry Jeroen, I meant programatically.

Comment: Maybe you could take a look in the controller for that page?

Comment: Bedankt Jeroen! :-)

Comment: edited to help you in the right direction

Comment: It works for the 'Manage Titles (Size, Color, etc.)' part, but not for the 'Manage Options (values of your attribute)'. Thanks!

Comment: hey, forgot the value array wrapper

Comment: The thing is, I want to be able to update single (
        1 => 'Store 1 value',
        2 => 'Store 2 value',) for each value and for each store. There is no backend model for the 'Color' attribute in MySQL. I want to check if a 'color' is in the Admin area, then update the values for the StoreViews, if not I want to save a new entry for Admin and the Storeviews(as in your code).

Comment: then you should get all options, overwrite yours and set them again. Or update in the database, there is no model for the values itself(so getting and setting is the best way to go)

Comment: Do you mean I have to delete the existing values, then creating new ones with the same admin keys? Setting new options works well('var_dump' shows the new value), but when I save, it creates a new set with the same Admin key and StoreView values.

Comment: If you provide the full array again and update yours it works just fine.

Comment: What do you mean under the full array? How can I get it? Do you mean all the lines with  the 'Admin' Keys and 'StoreView' values?

Comment: I've updated my answer to a full working piece of code. Happy to help you out

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Default option value is not defined' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mag\app\Mage.php:595 Stack trace: #0

Comment: oh no, I should go to bed yesterday ;) I will update my answer one last time

Comment: Jeroen, you are the man!!!

Many many thanks!!!

Tsjonge, jonge, jonge!

Comment: Cool! Sorry, I am new on this forum.

Comment: Hi Jeroen!

Would there be a way to do the same thing without using:

$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()
        ->getBlockSingleton('adminhtml/catalog_product_attribute_edit_tab_options');

Is it a good idea to work on the block directly? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jeroen!

What does this line do? - Mage::register('entity_attribute', $attribute);

Why isn't it saved in a variable?

Comment: Hi Stepan, you could life without the block, but it takes care about a lot, so you do not need to think(read copy/paste) about it again. The block uses ->getAttribute internally where it gets the attribute from the registry that's why I have to put it in there first.