# Problem saving Magento Attribute with modified attribute option label

Tags: magento-1.9, eav

I have the following code where I am trying to change a 'color' attribute option label:

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();

$attributeId = 92; // color

/** @var $attribute \Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute */
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
$attribute->load($attributeId);

// Register attribute for the easy use of the existing block
Mage::register('entity_attribute', $attribute);

// Use options tab from edit to easy get values    
/** @var $block \Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Edit_Tab_Options */
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()
        ->getBlockSingleton('adminhtml/catalog_product_attribute_edit_tab_options');

// Get current labels, easy...

$label = $block->getLabelValues();

// Build options array

$options = array('value' => array());
foreach ($block->getOptionValues() as $optionValue) {
    $storeOption = array();
    foreach (Mage::app()->getStores() as $store) {
        $key = 'store' . $store->getId();
        $storeOption[$store->getId()] = $optionValue->$key;
    }
    $options['value'][] = $storeOption;
}

// Show output

var_dump($label);
var_dump($options);

// Update value 0 for store 2

$options['value'][0][2] = 'New value';

// Update and save data

$attribute->setFrontendLabel($label)->setOption($options)->save();
```

=====================================================================

When I am launching the script, I get the following Fatal Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Default option value is not defined' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mag\app\Mage.php:595 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mag\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Resource\Entity\Attribute.php(353): Mage::throwException('Default option ...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mag\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Resource\Entity\Attribute.php(198): Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute->_saveOption(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mag\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Attribute.php(61): Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute->_afterSave(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mag\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(463): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Attribute->_afterSave(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mag\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute))
#5 C:\xampp\htdo in C:\xampp\htdocs\mag\app\Mage.php on line 595
```

Does anyone know why?

Thanks a lot!

===========================================================================

Here is how the var_dump() of the $options variable looks like:

```
array(1) {
  ["value"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      [1]=>
      string(0) ""
      [6]=>
      string(5) "GREEN"
      [2]=>
      string(9) "New GREEN"
      [3]=>
      string(5) "GRUEN"
      [4]=>
      string(5) "VERDE"
      [5]=>
      string(5) "VERDE"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(6) {
      [1]=>
      string(0) ""
      [6]=>
      string(4) "BLUE"
      [2]=>
      string(4) "BLEU"
      [3]=>
      string(4) "BLAU"
      [4]=>
      string(3) "BLU"
      [5]=>
      string(4) "AZUL"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is thrown in the method `Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute::_saveOption` by this code:

```
if (!isset($values[0])) {
    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('eav')->__('Default option value is not defined'));
}
```

This means that `$values[0]` is not set

`$values` comes from this code in the same method `foreach ($option['value'] as $optionId => $values) {`

Apparently in your code `$options['value'][Some numeric key here][0]` is not set. See how the `$options` array looks like before passing it to the `setOption` method (last line in your code).

Comment: Thanks a lot marius!

$options['value'][Some numeric key here][0] was the admin value that I do not want to change. I want it to remain the same and only update the other options for each StoreView.

Comment: How do you set the $options['value'][Some numeric key here][0] to what it actually is in the Database?

Many thanks!

Comment: How do you set the $options['value'][Some numeric key here][0] to what it actually is in the Database? Do you have to save it again in order to update the other ones? Thank you very much! Promiss, no more fishing ;-).

Comment: Post in your question how the `$values` var looks like.

Comment: both of your array elements are missing the `0` key. that's the option label for the admin store. You should try to replace this line `foreach (Mage::app()->getStores() as $store) {` with `foreach (Mage::app()->getStores(true) as $store) {`

Comment: It does not work as I want.

It adds a new set of values for the array where I change the StoreView values (it does not update the existing translations).

Comment: It's ok, actually in $options['value'][Some numeric key here][0] one has to put the 'option_id' in the [Some numeric key here]. Thanks Marius! You are very kind!

Comment: It was my [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59226/update-translations-of-color-attribute-label/59356#59356) to another question. Which I've updated! `getStores(true)`