# Get data directly from block in a shell script

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, shell

Is there anything wrong with getting data directly from Block, and not from Model or resource? If yes, what are the threats? I mean, like this:

```
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()
    ->getBlockSingleton('adminhtml/catalog_product_attribute_edit_tab_options');

$label = $block->getLabelValues();
```

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still working and have doubts on my [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59226/update-translations-of-color-attribute-label).

Like I said before in the comments, you could also implement the underlaying functionality in your code. It is just a useful way of not having to copy/paste good code to another location.

In this case, the block has a lot of easy to use features to work with attribute options.

You could also try to understand the underlaying code in the block and implement it accordingly.

*More than happy to help you out.*

Comment: Cool, Mr Jeroen!

Thanks! You have explained it quite well!

Have you seen my new question?

Comment: Which question?